# How to Read Records From Any Database Table and Export As TextFile Using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am building a spring batch job that will be invoked through a webservice. The webservice will take a list of select and delete statement pairs. The records returned by the select statement will be saved as a CSV on the filesystem and then those same records will be deleted by executing the supplied delete statement.

I have seen a number of ColumnRowMapper examples but that requires me to create a POJO for each table entity. I am looking for a solution that will handle any column from any table. Any suggestions on approach?

****UPDATE****
Since writing this post, I've landed on the following solution.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, ?>> getRowsOfDataForExportFromTable(){
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, ? extends Object>> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    databaseReader.setDataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
    databaseReader.setSql("select * from SOME_TABLE where last_updated_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);");
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new RowMapper<Map<String, ? extends Object>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, ? extends Object> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            Map<String,String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            int numOfColumns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int j = 1; j < numOfColumns+1; j++){
                String columnName = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(j);
                String value = resultSet.getString(j);
                resultMap.put(columnName,value);
            }

            return resultMap;
        }
    });
    return databaseReader;
}
```

The above ItemReader will build a LinkedHashMap row mapper where the column name is the key and the column value is the value.

Comment: Please show any code which you have tried.

Comment: I am new to Spring batch so I've only reviewed ColumnRowMapper samples that require a POJO . I can't find any examples that use a Map and how define dynamic number columns.

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution I ended up going with, please provide feedback if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `Map` instead of `POJO`? You can dynamically fill it in `Reader`, and then create `CSV` file from this `Map`.

Comment: Can this be done for multiple tables ? I haven't been able to find a good example of this , do you have any references that you can share?

Comment: You can see at `FieldSet` as example

Comment: I've accepted your answer to use a Map and I've updated the question with the solution I ended up using.